# Use a specified key from ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, github

Along the lines of [How to tell git which private key to use?](https://superuser.com/questions/232373/tell-git-which-private-key-to-use)
I would like to use a specific ssh key in a given situation.

My problem is that even when I specify '-i something' ssh uses the keys from my ssh-agent in the order they are added.

My specific situation:

- I have two github users, each with their own key
  I would like to - for example via a ssh-config - for each clone specify which key to use:

```
   Host USER1.git
     Hostname github.com
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/USER1.id_rsa
```

`ssh -vt USER1.git` will still use `USER2.id_rsa` if that is the key first added to ssh-agent.

Answer (score 13):

The point is to use the **public key file** inside `IdentityFile` directive.

```
Host USER1.git
  User git
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/USER1.id_rsa.pub

Host USER2.git
  User git
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/USER2.id_rsa.pub
```

If we specify the private key inside the SSH config, SSH agent will fail to pick the right key if the private key is encrypted.

A similar question on stackexchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495785/264704

Answer (score 8):

I finally got it to work:

```
Host USER1.git
  User git
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/USER1.id_rsa

Host USER2.git
  User git
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/USER2.id_rsa
```

- Indentation counts.
- Do `ssh-add -l` and make sure both of your keys have been added.

  - Copy/paste each path from `ssh-add -l` into the appropriate line in `~/.ssh/config` to avoid typos.  If there is a `~/.ssh/config` identityfile path typo for USER1, then the wrong key (USER2's key) will be used instead.

I got the instructions over at BitBucket. They should work for GitHub since the only difference is `HostName`: http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168#ConfiguringMultipleSSHIdentitiesforGitBashMacOSXLinux-CreateaSSHconfigfile

To get this to work on a remote server using agent forwarding, try @stijn-hoop's suggestion below (in the comments section of this answer).

Comment: For your last comment re agent forwarding, see this answer:

http://superuser.com/questions/273037/using-the-identityfile-directive-in-ssh-config-when-agentforwarding-is-in-use

Answer (score 2):

Use `IdentitiesOnly yes` below these hosts, in .ssh/config.

Comment: but then it will not use the agent and force me to enter passphrase for all github connections

Comment: Yes, this is how it works. You can't choose between different keys when using ssh-agent. One way is to start multiple ssh-agents and switch between them either using different wrappers for different github operations or just switching between ssh-agents (changing SSH_AUTH_SOCK)

Comment: The comment above is incorrect -- you CAN choose identities from your ssh-agent. See also the answer I already mentioned above,

http://superuser.com/questions/273037/using-the-identityfile-directive-in-ssh-config-when-agentforwarding-is-in-use