# Over SSH, can you use the same private key on the host side for other purposes?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-keys

I'm sat on one computer ('client') and connecting through SSH to another computer ('host') using my private key.

On the host computer, I would like to clone a Git repo using the private key that's stored on the client computer.

[image]

**Is this possible?** (Without copying the private key over to the host computer.)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It did indeed work! You can write an answer, it's as simple as "use SSH agent forwarding, here's a guide on GitHub"

Comment: Link-only answers are low quality. I aim higher. Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Theory

The functionality you seek is called "SSH agent forwarding". It works like this:

1. There is an agent (a program, commonly `ssh-agent`) running in your local computer (or already forwarded from elsewhere). Other programs can communicate with the agent via a UNIX-domain socket, if only they know the path to the socket. Proper setup provides the right path.
2. You add keys to the agent on demand (`ssh-add …`), or programs like `ssh` add keys they use (if they are configured to do so).
3. Programs use the agent instead of using the key(s) on their own. In terms of [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1657396/432690) we would say they ask the agent to solve puzzles for them.
4. You use `ssh -A` locally to connect to an SSH server. Programs you then run on the server will be able to communicate with your local agent. Anything you run that knows how to talk to an agent or uses `ssh` under the hood will be able to use your local agent. The fact the agent is on another computer won't matter for them.

---

#### Starting an agent

There are few ways to start an agent:

1. Some systems are configured to start an agent when a user logs in. Each user gets their own agent. Your OS may have already started an agent for you. In a shell invoke:

   ```
   env | grep '^SSH_AUTH_SOCK='
   ```

   Non-empty output means the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable is in the environment. The value of it is (or at least should be) the path to the UNIX-domain socket that allows programs to communicate with the already running agent. Programs find the socket by checking this exact environment variable. The existence of the variable normally means an agent is running and ready. A variable named `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` that doesn't point to the socket of your running agent is abnormal (something went wrong).

   If you see the variable then most likely an agent is there for you. Proceed to the next section of this answer.
2. You can start an agent by invoking `ssh-agent` in a shell, but don't do this directly. You want programs to be able to find the right variable in the environment. Sole `ssh-agent` cannot alter the environment of its parent shell. It prints commands designed to be evaluated by the shell, so the shell itself changes its own environment. You can invoke `ssh-agent` to see what it prints, but then `kill` the PID you learn from the output, otherwise the useless agent will keep running in vain.

   The right command is:

   ```
   eval "`ssh-agent`"
   ```

   There are few things that need explanation:

   - [`eval` can be dangerous](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), you may have heard that "`eval` is evil". Here it's the right thing because `ssh-agent` is one of few tools specifically designed to be used with `eval` safely.
   - Different shells require different syntax. What `ssh-agent` prints needs to match the shell. The tool prints shell code valid either in `sh` (and shells with similar syntax, e.g. Bash) or in `csh` (and shells with similar syntax). `ssh-agent` guesses the right style by examining the `SHELL` variable; if it cannot guess then it will generate code for `sh`. You can explicitly tell it what style you need by using `-s` (for `sh`-like shells) or `-c` (for `csh`-like shells). The command will be like:

     ```
     eval "`ssh-agent -s`"
     ```

     If you want to see the difference, invoke `ssh-agent -s` and `ssh-agent -c` without `eval`. Don't forget to `kill` the right PIDs afterward.
   - Nowadays we often use `$()` instead of backticks (and it's the right thing, [`$()` is better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/108618)), but `$()` doesn't work in `csh`. This answer uses backticks to be equally useful in `sh`-like shells *and* in `csh`-like shells.

   After the `eval …` command, `env | grep '^SSH_AUTH_SOCK='` should show you something. The agent will run until you kill it. The most proper way to kill the agent is:

   ```
   eval "`ssh-agent -k`"
   ```

   in the same shell as before (use `-s` xor `-c` if needed). Without `eval` the command is able to kill the agent but the variables will stay in the environment of the shell. No matter what you do in this shell, the variables will stay in the environments of child processes that inherited them and are still running.
3. Yet another way of starting an agent is like this:

   ```
   ssh-agent some_command …
   ```

   The tool will start an agent and then run `some_command …` in the right environment. `some_command` may be `bash`, i.e. if you do:

   ```
   ssh-agent bash
   ```

   then you will find yourself in an interactive Bash where `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is already in the environment (note if your original shell is also Bash then it may seem the command did nothing; like invoking `bash` from Bash may seem a no-op, until you `exit` and find out you're still in Bash).

   The agent exits automatically when `some_command` terminates, no maintenance is needed. This method is quite straightforward.

   If you need an agent only for one local `ssh` then `some_command` may be the `ssh`. In your case you need `ssh -A`:

   ```
   ssh-agent ssh -A …
   ```

   Depending on what key(s) you want to use and the configuration of `ssh`, the above may or may not be a good idea. In some circumstances you may want to do something with the agent before you run `ssh -A` (like adding keys, see below).

---

#### Adding keys to an agent

When an agent starts, it does not have any private keys. If you find an agent started by your OS, it's theoretically possible the OS not only started the agent but also added some key(s). Keys are added using `ssh-add` or by `ssh` when `AddKeysToAgent` is set in `ssh_config`.

In a shell with access to an agent (`SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in the environment, the agent running) invoke:

```
ssh-add -l
```

to see keys (identities) represented by the agent. There may be none. To add a key run:

```
ssh-add path/to/key
```

Note `ssh-add` without arguments probes some standard pathnames and adds files it finds. See [`man 1 ssh-add`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-add) for details.

If `AddKeysToAgent` is set in `ssh_config` (by default it's not) or if you request it in the command line, `ssh` itself will add the key it uses. This means if you want to use the same key to authenticate to the server and later on the server then you don't need `ssh-add`. You can do:

```
# with agent already running
ssh -A -o AddKeysToAgent=yes …
```

This works with keys specified with `-i` as well. These are the circumstances that allow you to run an agent and `ssh` in one command (the method mentioned at the end of the previous section):

```
# already running agent (if any) is irrelevant
# we are starting a new agent
ssh-agent ssh -A -o AddKeysToAgent=yes …
```

---

#### Invoking `ssh`

The relevant option is `-A`. From [`man 1 ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#A):

> `-A`
> Enables forwarding of connections from an authentication agent such as `ssh-agent(1)`. This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.

(The keyword in the configuration file is [`ForwardAgent`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ForwardAgent).)

The server may or may not allow forwarding. See `AllowAgentForwarding` and `DisableForwarding` in [`man 5 sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config).

Be warned:

> Agent forwarding should be enabled with caution. Users with the ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the agent's UNIX-domain socket) can access the local agent through the forwarded connection. An attacker cannot obtain key material from the agent, however they can perform operations on the keys that enable them to authenticate using the identities loaded into the agent. […]

If the server allows forwarding and the right key has been added to the local agent then `-A` is all you need to add to the `ssh` command you use to connect to the server. It may be as easy as:

```
ssh -A user@server
```

And with `ForwardAgent yes` in `ssh_config` (or in your `~/.ssh/config`) you don't even need `-A` in the command line, pure `ssh user@server` will do.

---

#### Situation on the server

If your local `ssh -A …` gives you an interactive remote shell then you can use the same command as we used earlier (locally), now on the server:

```
# on the server
env | grep '^SSH_AUTH_SOCK='
```

If the forwarding works then you will find the variable set. It's as if `ssh-agent` was running, but it's really the SSH server who listens on the socket and relays to your local `ssh-agent`. Programs that use the socket don't care. You can even forward the agent further (with `ssh -A` from the server to yet another computer).

Simply use `ssh` or another command able to talk to an agent. It should find the socket and talk to the local `ssh-agent`.

<sup>`ssh-add` is no different. It's not obvious, but if you use `ssh-add` on the server to add some key then the tool will actually add the key from the server (rather than telling your local `ssh-agent` to open a local file with the same path). You can disconnect from the server and your local agent will keep holding the added key. So a local `ssh-agent` not only allows you to use your local key on the server; it also allows you to use your key from the server to connect from your local to wherever. There's a big difference though. `ssh-agent` needs to store some representation of added keys, if only in memory. Local `ssh-add` talking to a local `ssh-agent` does not make the local key leave the local computer. Remote `ssh-add` talking to a local `ssh-agent` copies the remote key to local memory.</sup>

If your local `ssh -A …` specifies a command to run on the server (as opposed to an interactive shell), nothing will change in the mechanics of agent forwarding. The remote command will find `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in the environment and it will be able to talk to your local `ssh-agent`.

---

#### Possible problems (already solved), interesting cases

- [How do I get `ssh` to use only one key from ssh-agent?](https://superuser.com/q/1314837/432690)
- [SSH always using first key accepted by server](https://superuser.com/q/1610623/432690)

---

#### Documentation

- [`man 1 ssh-agent`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-agent)
- [`man 1 ssh-add`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-add)
- [`man 1 ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh)
- [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config)
- [`man 5 sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config)

---

#### Other

- [Guide on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/using-ssh-agent-forwarding)