# multiple ssh aliases selecting wrong user when forwarding

Tags: ssh

I'm following the [dual identity procedure for bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168):

I have 2 bitbucket accounts `ccmcbeck` and `chrisbeck`.  The former is personal, the latter is work.

On my local Mac, I have this in my `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *.work.com
  User chris
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_dsa
Host bitbucket-personal
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User ccmcbeck
  ForwardAgent no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_ccmcbeck_rsa
Host bitbucket-work
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User chrisbeck
  ForwardAgent no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_chrisbeck_rsa
```

On my local Mac I `ssh -T` all is good, I get:

```
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket-personal
logged in as ccmcbeck.
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket-work
logged in as chrisbeck.
```

On my local Mac, the ssh version is `OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011`

When I `ssh foo.work.com` to my Linux box, I get:

```
$ ssh-add -l
1024 ... /Users/chris/.ssh/work_dsa (DSA)
2048 ... /Users/chris/.ssh/bitbucket_ccmcbeck_rsa (RSA)
2048 ... /Users/chris/.ssh/bitbucket_chrisbeck_rsa (RSA)
```

On `foo.work.com`, I also have this in my `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host bitbucket-personal
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User ccmcbeck
  ForwardAgent no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_ccmcbeck_rsa
Host bitbucket-work
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User chrisbeck
  ForwardAgent no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_chrisbeck_rsa
```

However, on `foo.work.com` when I `ssh -T`, it references the wrong User for `git@bitbucket-work`

```
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket-personal
logged in as ccmcbeck.
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket-work
logged in as ccmcbeck.
```

On `foo.work.com`, the ssh version is `OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008`

Why is my configuration causing `foo.work.com` to reference the wrong User?

Comment: FWIW, if I `ssh-add -d` my `bitbucket-personal` identity, then `foo.work.com` uses the correct `User`

Comment: It also behaves the same on an AWS server that has `OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010`

Comment: Looks like the order in which the keys are added makes a difference.  IOW, `foo.work.com` uses the first one reported by `ssh-add -l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation seems to me that ssh-agent is using whatever key it has loaded at any time. You can drop this behavior by using the `IdentitiesOnly` directive in your config file, as follows:

```
 Host bitbucket-personal
 HostName bitbucket.org
 User ccmcbeck
 ForwardAgent no
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_ccmcbeck_rsa
 IdentitiesOnly yes

 Host bitbucket-work
 HostName bitbucket.org
 User chrisbeck
 ForwardAgent no
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_chrisbeck_rsa
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

From the `ssh man page`:

> Specifies that ssh(1) should only use the authentication identity files configured in the ssh_config files, even if ssh-agent(1) offers more identities. The argument to this keyword must be ''yes'' or ''no''. This option is intended for situations where ssh-agent offers many different identities. The default is ''no''.

EDIT:

In your post there are these lines, toward the very end:

```
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug2: key: /home/chrisb/.ssh/bitbucket_chrisbeck_rsa ((nil))
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
```

They clearly show this key was not accepted. This is why you always login as ccmcbeck: that key works, and without `IdentitiesOnly yes`, the client tried other keys until it found a working one. By introducing this restriction, we have at least clarified the nature of the problem.

Since from your Mac you do not seem to have such a problem, it must reside with the Linux client, and in particular the private key you are trying to use. Best thing is to generate a new one, local to Linux, and put its `.pub` counterpart among the `authorized_keys`. Hope this helps.

EDIT2:

...or you can follow [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/273037/using-the-identityfile-directive-in-ssh-config-when-agentforwarding-is-in-use) to select the private key you wish to use by 
specifying its public counterpart from the forwarded agent. The answer still requires the use of the `IdentitiesOnly yes` option.

Comment: I tried that and I get "permission denied" when I `ssh -T` to either alias.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Could you be more specific? By running ssh with the **-v** flag, please.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Please see my edit

Comment: Thanks @MariusMatutiae.  FWIW, both `ccmcbeck` and `chrisbeck` work if they are the first one in `ssh-add -l` without `IdentitiesOnly yes`.  With `IdentitiesOnly yes` on `work.foo.com`, ssh appears to only look for local keys, not the keys passed via the ssh agent on my Mac.

Comment: you were very close to the solution which is here http://superuser.com/questions/273037/using-the-identityfile-directive-in-ssh-config-when-agentforwarding-is-in-use.  Additionally I needed to put the pub key on `work.foo.com`and reference that in the `~/.ssh/config`.  If you'll update your answer, I'll accept

Comment: @ChrisBeck Done, very concisely, because it is not my idea really. But you are a real gentleman.