# How to be sure I'm using the right identity from my personal remote server?

Tags: ssh, git, gitlab

The company I work with and I are both using Gitlab as remote repo. To make it simple from my personal laptop I want to be able to connect on 2 distinct repo. The company's one and mine.
I'm using 2 accounts to achieve this purpose (personal and company)

Locally

I've configured 2 stanzas/sections into my ~/.ssh/config

```
Host gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
    ForwardAgent yes
Host company.gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company
    ForwardAgent yes
```

When I'm doing git operation from my local computer all is good.

The problems appear when I connect to my personal remote server and I try to git my repo.
And I receive error like

```
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

After some search it appears, git is using the bad identity.
If I'm doing `ssh-add -l` I get 2 fingerprints

```
4096 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxx personal_key (RSA)
4096 SHA256:yyyyyyyyyy company_key (RSA)
```

How to be sure only one identity is used from MY remote server on MY git repo ?
How to be sure I'm using the right identity from my personal remote server (the personal_key) ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

SuperUser suggest me the right post but I saw it after. [Solution is there](https://superuser.com/a/273094/911570).

All I need to do was :

- to copy my pubkey on my personal remote server `scp ~/.ssh/personal.pub user@remote.server:.ssh/`
- update my remote config file to add

```
Host gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal.pub
    User git
```

Thanks to [Chris Johnsen](https://superuser.com/users/14827/chris-johnsen)